# Is Singleton Instance of a service provided to child components?

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular-services, angular2-providers

Suppose there is a parent component P . Having two child components B and C .
I provide a service (MyService let's say) in the ElementInjector of P and Inject the service in the constructor of P component class.
I Inject the service again in the two child components B and C .

My question is whether the instance of the service available with B,C and P will be the same in this case ?

And what if I Inject the service only in the two child components B and C and NOT in the parent component P . Will B and C have separate Instances of the MyService service in this case ?

Here is an image to help visualize the components .
[image: Parent Component P with Child Components B and C]

Edit:

Service class :

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService(){
   constructor(){
console.log('My Service instantiated');
}
}
```

P component's class:

```
import {MyService} from '...';

@Component({

selector:'Pcomp',
...
providers:[MyService]
})

export class PComponent {
 constructor(public myservice:MyService){
}
}
```

Component B class :

```
import {MyService} from '...';

@Component({

selector:'Bcomp',
...

})

export class BComponent {
 constructor(public myservice:MyService){
}
}
```

Component C class:

```
import {MyService} from '...';

@Component({

selector:'Ccomp',
...
})

export class CComponent {
  constructor(public myservice:MyService){
}
}
```

Comment: For a more detailed answer, can you please share how you specified the Service (eg how does the `@Injectable` decorator look like) and how you pass / inject it in the other parts of your app?

Comment: The service is provided at the component level , Specifically at the @Component decorator of P's component class. `@Component({selector:'P',template:'...',providers:[MyService]})...`

Comment: Just share the code rough code in your first post, also of the service so we can see which options you pass into the `Injectable` decorator :)

Comment: Services are/were used as singletons across a module.
Since Angular 9, services are something more than just singletons now.
Again, It all depends on your usage of metadata specifically `providedIn` and `providers`.
 Take a look here, you can also limit your provider scope
with component https://angular.io/guide/providers#limiting-provider-scope-with-components 
. As provider is at P component level, in your case B and C should have same instance.

Comment: @bron1010 yes I also think so . All three P , B and C will share the same instance of the MyService  service .

Answer (score 0):

If you are using angular CLI, service will be generated with something like this

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
```

So service is generated as a singleton and that means only one instance can exist int an app. I think it is recommended to create a service as a singleton.

Comment: Whether or not a service *should* be a singleton and what is best practice ultimately comes down to what you want to achieve. Sometimes you want global singletons, other times you want singletons scoped by a feature-module (but newly instantiated for every emebdding module), .. - Again, depends on what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for clarifications!!! I never used services scoped by a feature-module.

Comment: You are welcome. For more info: https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services

Answer (score 0):

Services are/were used as singletons across a module.
Since Angular 9, services are something more than just singletons now. what I mean by this is
having new instance of service with a lazy loaded module.

> *Lazy loading is when you load modules only when you need them; for
> example, when routing.They aren’t loaded right away like with eagerly
> loaded modules. This means that any services listed in their provider
> arrays aren’t available because the root injector doesn’t know about
> these modules.*
> -- angular.io guide

Hence, It all depends on your usage of metadata especially using
`providedIn` in service injectable decorator and `providers` for component decorator.

In above case, if we limit `MyService` as a provider to a component, it will be limited to that
component. Mentioning a piece of above code as below.

```
@Component({
    selector:'Pcomp',
...
    providers:[MyService]
})
```

As provider is at `Pcomp` level, `Pcomp` and its descendant `Bcomp` and `Ccomp` can leverage `MyService` as a singleton.

Reference : https://angular.io/guide/providers#limiting-provider-scope-with-components